# Jsoup not getting text of few elements when parsing all the elements in a page

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I need to find key,value pairs in a web page with a known set of keys. For this, i am parsing all the elements in the web page using Jsoup in java. But i am unable to retrieve text of few elements during the iteration. 
I am using the below code to select all elements and iterating using forEach loop.

Elements elements = document.body().select("*");

Sample HTML:

```html
<div id="requisitionDescriptionInterface.ID1622.row1" class="contentlinepanel" title=""><h2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:htm="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ftl="http://www.taleo.net/ftl" class="no-change-header-inline"><span id="requisitionDescriptionInterface.ID1638.row1" class="subtitle" style="display: inline;" title="">Primary Location</span></h2><span class="inline">&nbsp;</span><span id="requisitionDescriptionInterface.ID1659.row1" class="text" title="">India-Noida</span></div>
```

Both the spans (with texts Primary Location, Noida-India) are being selected. I am able to verify this by printing IDs using element.id() 
I am also able to print the text 'Primary Location' but text 'India-Noida' is not being selected. I am using the method Element.ownText() to select the text.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: when I parse your html I can get two texts by
        for ( Element e : elements )
        {
            System.out.println( e.ownText( ) ) ;
        }

result : 
Primary Location
 
India-Noida

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit it and add your code and the output you get.

Comment: Found the problem. Some elements are populated after some time using ajax, javascript. As i was using below code to get the Document object
Jsoup.connect(url).get();
it was not waiting for these elements. I changed this to load using WebClient and it is working fine now. Now the code looks like 

String joPage = getJobDescriptionPage(url, getWebClient());
   Document document = Jsoup.parse(joPage);

getWebClient() is a method which returns WebClient object